# samba issue with Dell WiFi

Tags: wireless, dell, samba

So I am running Ubuntu 14.04 with gnome 3 desktop.  I have samba set up and configured, and has been running for many months.  My wife has a Dell 1545, windows 7 home 64 bit laptop.  She tried to access the ubuntu shares and could not.  Not sure when this stopped but all other ubuntu machines can access the shares.  Tried lots of stuff on the windows side to no avail.  Out of curiosity, I disabled the wireless and connected the laptop to the ethernet port.  Low and behold, I could now access the shares!  What do I configure to allow the WiFi connection to work? Its a Dell 1397 WLAN mini-card.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.  Windows is gone and Gnome Ubuntu has taken its place.  Should have done it long ago.  Windows 7 Home is just too problematic with Samba.  Had a hell of a time getting it to work in the first place, and then it was not reliable.  Not putting any more effort into windows, we are now an Ubuntu family.